# Optimization of iOS6+ images game

Tags: ios, optimization

I have a game on the Apple Store, we make it to iPhone with retina & non-retina images. We are exporting to iPad and making it universal app.

But the main problem it's that the app its 45MB without iPad with iPad retina & non-retina, I think will get more than 100MB

I was thinking removing the normal images and leave the @2x as the normal images. And for preventing 3GS devices I upgrade it to iOS7.

What do you think? or how do you solve this issues in your games?

Note: we have the app in spanish & english, and because we render some text with shadows and stuff, we add it as images, so in some cases we have 8 assets per image :S

Thanks!

Comment: what is the size of the average image you are using? anything you can do there in terms of compression?

Comment: @JanR there is no rules, The big image it's the map (scrolling map) with about 4000x500 the non-retina. We are cropping it in 10 small pieces. But we have images from 16x16 :S

Comment: But in terms of filesize?

Comment: @JanR, the biggest its 2.3MB map -retina. The mean 30-50kb. we have almost 500 images (remember 2 english, and 2 spanish). All the images are PNG, and I already compress them to the maximum

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is not supplying all the images in the package and use a download to grab the image that is needed, so you won't need 4 versions, but you download say the english one if that's required. It does require the app to have internet connection though which might be undesirable.